# StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush as GradientStop

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am developing an application wherein I have to set one of the GradientStops as PhoneAccentColor StaticResource and I have to do this in the code (i.e. C#).

Here's what I have already tried:

```
GradientStop accentGS = new GradientStop();
accentGS.Color = (System.Windows.Media.Color)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
accentGS.Offset = .5;
lgbBlack.GradientStops.Add(accentGS);
```

Here, lgbBlack is the LinearGradientBrush to which I am adding this GradientStop.

This doesn't throw any error but when I run the application a 'System.InvalidCastException' is thrown and the application crashes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `PhoneAccentBrush` resource is a `SolidColorBrush`, not a `Color`.
That code should work:

```
GradientStop accentGS = new GradientStop();
SolidColorBrush c = (SolidColorBrush)App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
accentGS.Color = c.Color;
accentGS.Offset = .5;
lgbBlack.GradientStops.Add(accentGS);
```